# On running reactjs project using npm run build, getting error--postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Attribute without value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-run

Code works fine over npm start. But while running over npm-run-build, showing following error:

```
react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Attribute without value
Line: 0
Column: 60
Char: d
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! matchtimings@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the matchtimings@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

screenshot of the error:

[image: error snap shot]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error might come when we have used svg data URI in encoded format somewhere in code such as background-image: url('data:image/svg xml...).

So, just decode that encoded svg URI content using any URL encoder/decoder online([URI decoder](https://mothereff.in/url)) and replace that decoded svg content there

For example :

**Encoded URI**

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg width=12 height=12 fill=none stroke=%23dc3545 viewBox=0 0 12 12%3e%3ccircle cx=6....');
```

**Decoded URI**

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg xml,<svg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg width=12 height=12 fill=none stroke=#dc3545 viewBox=0 0 12 12>......</svg>');
```